# TCL GUI tcl_precision

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm using tclsh8.4.19 and the text values that get printed using tcl_precision 3 are upto 5 decimal places. i.e when i create a widget in tk gui the text values are uspto 5 decimal places and i want them to be upto 3 decimals only.

```
label $base.main.parameter($i).ParamValue($i,$j)  -text "$myvalue" \
                               -font {times 11 bold} -relief sunken
```

Now if the value of myvalue is .3456789 then the text printed is .3456789 and the value i want
to be printed is .345. So, I thought of using setting tcl_precision 3 but with no success.

Do I need to use something else. Please explain.

Answer (score 3):

The TCL help documnetion warns against changing tcl_precision; it is provided in modern version for backwards compatability only.  To achieve what you need to do the format command would be a much better choice:

```
set a 0.123456    
format %.3lf $a
```

shows converting a number to a string with three decimal places.

The absolute value for the precision can be replaced by an *, in this case the preceision is taken from the the next argument to the format command.

```
set precesion 3
set v 1.2345678
format %.*lf $precesion $v
1.235
```

Full details on using the format command can be found in its manual page, one online version can be found [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm)

Comment: if I want it to be like this: set a  0.123456 ; set b 3 ; format %."$b"lf $a . Is there any way that i can get it working this way?

Answer (score 1):

To round a value to a particular number of decimal places for display, use `format`.

```
set a 0.123654
set rounded [format "%.3f" $a]
```

You can specify the rounding places from a variable too:

```
set a 0.123654
set b 3
set rounded [format "%.*f" $b $a]
```

Though it's also equally possible (if perhaps less safe if you can't force `$b` to be an integer) to just construct the format string with substitutions:

```
set rounded [format "%.${b}f" $a]
```

Comment: And don't touch `tcl_precision` if you can help it; the effects are subtle and likely to surprise. The default is good enough for 99.99% of scripts.

Comment: In fact, if you were using Tcl 8.5 then the default setting of `tcl_precision` is magic, saying to use as few decimal digits as possible to precisely represent the (binary floating point) number. That's virtually always what people want (well, except when they didn't know about some of the limitations of binary IEEE floats in the first place).